# How do I run Code.exe in PowerShell and redirect errors when it is in Path or in Set-Alias?

Tags: powershell, redirect

I have Visual Studio Code running on a USB Drive. I would like to run `Code.exe` from PowerShell with its regular functionality (i.e. usually opening files [e.g. `Code.exe file1.txt file2.txt`]) by setting an alias for it or by putting it in my `$env:Path`. However, running it either one of these ways has `Code.exe` output its errors to the terminal:

```
[main 2024-02-23T21:43:27.202Z] update#setState idle
[16264:0223/144329.744:ERROR:jump_list.cc(300)] Failed to append custom category 'Recent Folders & Workspaces' to Jump List due to system privacy settings.
[main 2024-02-23T21:43:29.758Z] updateWindowsJumpList#setJumpList unexpected result: customCategoryAccessDeniedError
[main 2024-02-23T21:43:29.873Z] WSL is not installed, so could not detect WSL profiles
[main 2024-02-23T21:43:39.634Z] Extension host with pid 7200 exited with code: 0, signal: unknown.
```

These errors are distracting when trying to work in the terminal. Is there a way to keep `Code.exe` from producing them?

---

I tried to put `code.cmd` in my PATH but occasionally it would fail to open a file from the command line, spitting out: `'#' is not recognized as an internal or external command,`... I looked at `code.cmd`---just a batch script similar to function below---and saw little on how I could resolve it. I have been using mklement0's function for a bit now and it seems to be working good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Code.exe` isn't designed to be invoked *directly*; Visual Studio Code's designated CLI entry point is the `code.cmd` *batch file*, located in the `bin` subdirectory of where `Code.exe` is located.

`code.cmd` automatically suppresses the - asynchronously arriving - diagnostic messages that print to the console you've experienced.

Therefore, you should make your alias invoke `code.cmd` / add `code.cmd`'s directory to `$env:PATH` (`code.cmd` is located in the `bin` subfolder of where `Code.exe` resides).

---

To recreate what `code.cmd` does in a direct call to `Code.exe`, you'd need a *wrapper function* along the following lines:

```
function code {

  $prev1 = $env:ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE; $env:ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE=1
  $prev2 = $env:VSCODE_DEV; $env:VSCODE_DEV = [NullString]::Value

  # This uses the path of a user-level VS Code installation.
  # Adjust as needed to point to the dir. in which Code.exe
  # resides on your USB drive.
  $exeDir = "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Programs\Microsoft VS Code"

  & "$exeDir\Code.exe" "$exeDir\resources\app\out\cli.js" @args

  $env:ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE = $prev1
  $env:VSCODE_DEV = $prev2

}
```

Comment: Ahh. Much better. I wanted to use VSC to be able to diff and look through files. This helps me out. Thank you.